# Get null at String path= properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");

Tags: java, digital-signature

This is my code. I am trying to sign pdf with digital signature e-token.

```
public static String PATH = "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/New.properties";
    /** Some properties used when signing. */
    public static Properties properties = new Properties();
```

New.properties file is :

```
PUBLIC     C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/public.cer
ROOTCERT    c:/examples/signatures/CACertSigningAuthority.crt
PRIVATE     c:/examples/signatures/private.p12
PASSWORD    123456
```

But in code I get null from properties .
The code is here:

```
    String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
    String keystore_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
    String key_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");`
```

I get path,keystore_password,key_password null.
What is the error there?

Comment: "sing pdf with digital signature" or "sign pdf with digital signature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to load the properties file as follows:-

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(YOUR_PATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the property file using:

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream(PATH));
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add `=` sign in property file like:-

```
PUBLIC = C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/public.cer
ROOTCERT = C:/examples/signatures/CACertSigningAuthority.crt
PRIVATE = C:/examples/signatures/private.p12
PASSWORD = 123456
```

Comment: `=` is optional. Property file is good. See examples in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)